# Cracked ceramic plate water damage/discoloration?

Tags: ceramic

I noticed some discoloration on some dishes I have. I assume this is from water seeping into the dish someway. Is there anything I can do to fix?

This dish around the crack which it seems water has seeped in.
[image]

Comment: @rumtscho, that is a false duplicate.  The plates in the photo are actually cracked, whereas the linked question is about glaze crazing.  We do not have a reference question about cracked dishes, so please reopen.

Comment: Victor: your first photo is poor quality, I can't tell what you're trying to show.

Comment: @FuzzyChef OK, if you can see a difference in the damage, I'll reopen.

Comment: Thanks.  Now this one can become our reference question about cracked dishes

Comment: I can upload a better picture later today

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't comment on the first plate, since your photo is poor.

The second plate has a straight-up crack in it.  Given that the crack is discolored at the edge and faint in the center, it's clearly spreading and will soon result in the plate splitting apart. Given the shape of the crack, it looks like a flaw in the plate itself rather than impact damage (from you hitting it on something), although I'd need to see the underside of the plate to be sure.

While there are ways to fix cracks in dining ware, none of them are great or attractive; it will always be obvious that this plate has been repaired.  If other plates in the set are having problems, let me suggest that you'd be better off with a different set of plates.  If all of the plates are cracking, they may have other things wrong with them that you can't see, such as using unsafe glazes.

Warning aside, if you want to repair it, the most effective method is to crack it the rest of the way in half, and then glue it back together using a [food-safe epoxy](https://www.permabond.com/industries_served/food-safe-epoxy-adhesive/).

Background: I'm a potter of 30 years experience.

Comment: It depends on your perspective of attractive.  There’s kintsugi, which is a japanese repair method where you add gold dust to highlight the repair:  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kintsugi

Comment: I added some markup to the first plate to showcase the different colors in the picture. The shading is very similar to the shading around the crack in the second plate.

Comment: That picture is still too dark to see anything.  If you wanted a comment on that plate, you'd need to take a new photo, not just mark up the old one.  If it's the same problem, though, you don't need to bother.